# List of items, form, response on the same page. What am I missing?

Tags: django

I have general.html page...

In the general.html page included query_page.html... The purpose of the query_page.html is to return the list of objects, which are the buttons to detailed descriptions of themselves. It does it... Now, I'm trying to include the form into this same page with the reference to the same query_page (so on itself, so the action="" or action="{% url 'for_queries' %}")...  So the result of the search will be shown on the very same page. The form searches through the list of the objects by query_id, and should return one item which matches query id of items... The form and response are easy and by the book, but I don't see the result of the search... The view function itself, it seems, doesn't react on the action...

I tried to include print statements into the function, none returned in the command prompt... I see the q object in the search line and in the command prompt though... So it should be posted into the view function, but somehow it doesn't(?most likely) or the function doesn't return the result to the page...

I also tried to change the view function from using request and sitting in views.py by itself to to be included in the class with the according model and using self.

What am I missing?

query_page.html:

```
{% extends "generic.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% block css %}
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/styles.css' %}">>
{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
<body>
    <div>
        <h3><span class="colorfull">List of queries: </span></h3>
        {% if forquery_list %}
        <ul>
            {% for item in forquery_list %}
            <li>
                <a class="text-white" href="{{ item.get_absolute_url }}"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary my-1"><h10>Item number - {{item.query_id}} , Kind - {{item.kind}}, search time - {{item.search_time}}</h10></button></a>
            </li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
        {% else %}
            <p>No queries? Really?</p>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
    <div>
        <form action="{% url 'for_queries' %}" method="get">
            <input type="text" name="q">
            <input type="submit" value="Search">
        </form>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p>Some info. request.get['q']</p> #text shows up. request.get was in the wrong place.
        {% for query in queries %}
            <p>{{query.query_id}}, {{query.kind}}, {{query.search_time}}</p>#tried at least get text
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</body>
{% endblock %}
```

views.py:

```
class BooksListView(generic.ListView):
    model=ForQuery
    paginate_by=10

    def search_queries(self):
        print('start of the function')#nothing printed in cmd
        query = self.request.GET.get('q')
        if query is not None:
            query=query.strip()
        if not query:
            return ForQuery.objects.none()
        else:
            queries = ForQuery.objects.filter(Q(query_id__icontains=query))
            for query in queries:
                print('query_id: %s' %query.query_id)#nothing in cmd
            return queries
```

I didn't use forms.py for the sake of simplicity.

Comment: where have you called this method inside your class --> search_queries .

Comment: path('books/', views.BooksListView.as_view(), name='for_queries') -my gosh, exactly... I'm not calling the method. I'm calling the list of books, but I'm not calling the function...

Comment: I doubt that I can have 2 similar paths referencing one method the other one class... Thank you for a good point...